# How to automate the filename process when downloading an image with python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not a coder at all I'm just learning bits and bobs so I can get some faces for my art project. I want to download 100 faces from the [thispersondoesnotexist](https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com) website and I have so far gotten this far with my code.

```
 import urllib.request
 urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com", "image.jpg")
```

The code downloads the face and saves it as "image.jpg" but when I run it again it overwrites the image I just saved. How can I find out how to write code that will randomly generate a filename? I'm using the PyCharm IDE.

Comment: Are you trying to download multiple images from the same site ?

Comment: yes but a new image only appears when the page is refreshed

Comment: I have added an answer, you may please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate random file names you can include this piece of code.

This code will generate a random string of length 6 and uses it as the filename everytime you run the program.

```
import random
import string
import urllib.request

filename = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k = 6)) + '.jpg'

urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com", filename)
```

Comment: Thank you! It would have taken me forever to get that on my own but even downloading the one image made me want to learn more this stuff is fun. Thanks again!

Comment: How to ensure the filename will not be the same as some other previous name and overwrite the older one? How likely (or unlikely) this can happen? Technically, you won't be able to generate more than `(#string.ascii_uppercase + #string.digits) ^ k` unique filenames...no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way can be generating timestamp and use it to name a file:

```
import urllib.request
import datetime

def generate_timestamp():
    return str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace('-', '_').replace(':', '_').replace(' ', '__')

urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com", "image_" + generate_timestamp() + ".jpg")
```

This will serve dual purposes:

1. Naming a file uniquely.
2. Getting idea when it has finished downloading.

Comment: thank you aswell! this stuff is super interesting, I actually want to learn more